# How to get by Webservice PHP-MySQL image in base 64?

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

**I need print this  "print json_encode($datos); the image in base64.**

Hello friends will see I want to get all the records of a table called CATEGORIES with the fields IDCATEGORIA, NAMECATEGORIES, IMAGENCATEGORI using a Webservice maked in PHP and MYSQL and show it to me in a JSON, the problem is that the Webservice only returns me IDCATEGORY and NAMECATEGORIES BUT IMAGENCATEGORI does not show it, it is my first time to manage Webservices with PHP, I have only occupied Webservices with Java and as far as in Java it was necessary to obtain the field IMAGENCATEGORIA of the database and convert that image to base64 then to show it as a String of characters in base64 next to the other data already forming the JSON, someone would know how to implement that in my PHP code, here I leave the PHP file:

Sorry for my English is very bad xD

Meta.php

```
/**
 * Representa el la estructura de las metas
 * almacenadas en la base de datos
 */
require 'Database.php';

class Meta
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Retorna en la fila especificada de la tabla 'meta'
     *
     * @param $idMeta Identificador del registro
     * @return array Datos del registro
     */
    public static function getAll()
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM meta";
        try {
            // Preparar sentencia
            $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
            // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
            $comando->execute();

            return $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

obtener_metas.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Obtiene todas las metas de la base de datos
 */

require 'Meta.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    // Manejar petición GET
    $metas = Meta::getAll();

    if ($metas) {

        $datos["estado"] = 1;
        $datos["metas"] = $metas;

        print json_encode($datos);
    } else {
        print json_encode(array(
            "estado" => 2,
            "mensaje" => "Ha ocurrido un error"
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not very clear, from your question, whether the `IMAGENCATEGORI` field contains an actual image (raw image stored as a BLOB) or, for example, a file name or path.

Following is how I would amend your `if ($metas)` block inside `obtener_metas.php`.

#### 1. If IMAGENCATEGORI field is your image, stored as a blob

```
if ($metas) {
    $datos["estado"] = 1;
    $datos["metas"] = [];
    foreach($metas as $meta) {
      // Push an entry in the new array, replacing raw image with base64-encoded
      $datos["metas"][] = array(
        'IDCATEGORIA'     => $meta['IDCATEGORIA'],
        'NAMECATEGORIES'  => $meta['NAMECATEGORIES'],
        'IMAGENCATEGORIA' => base64_encode($meta['IMAGENCATEGORIA']),
      );
    }
    print json_encode($datos);
} else {
    // your original code
}
```

#### 2. If IMAGENCATEGORI field is your image's file name/path

Almost the same, only you need to read the file from the filesystem first.

```
$imagesPath = '/path/to/your/images'; // replace with actual path
if ($metas) {
    $datos["estado"] = 1;
    $datos["metas"] = [];
    foreach($metas as $meta) {
      // Push an entry in the new array, replacing raw image with base64-encoded
      $imgFileContents = file_get_contents($imagesPath . '/' . $meta['IMAGENCATEGORIA'];
      $datos["metas"][] = array(
        'IDCATEGORIA'     => $meta['IDCATEGORIA'],
        'NAMECATEGORIES'  => $meta['NAMECATEGORIES'],
        'IMAGENCATEGORIA' => base64_encode($imgFileContents),
      );
    }
    print json_encode($datos);
} else {
    // your original code
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know please!

Comment: Thank you very much brother, this is exactly what I needed :D